# HDIV confidentiality true problam with Select element

Tags: java, security, spring-mvc, config, hdiv

I am populating a select element using EL values and getting problem

```
<form:select path="district" cssClass="inputText">
    <option value="" title='${SELECT_DISTRICT}'>
       <c:out value="--${SELECT_DISTRICT}--"></c:out>
    </option>
    <form:options items="${districtList}"/>
</form:select>
```

When i have changed configuration confidentiality="true" in hdiv-config.xml it is giving select values as incrementing number starting from "0" and while making confidentiality="false" populating values as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand exactly what is your issue, because it seems you are describing the HDIV confidentiality behaviour. I mean, when the confidentiality is activated HDIV hides real values (using instead relative values such as:0,1,2..) and when the confidentiality is deactivated render real values.

Could you give please more information about the issue?

Anyway when you use select tag (I suppose you are using Spring MVC tags) you should use also spring mvc option tag:

```
<form:select path="username">
    <form:option value="j2ee" label="j2ee" />
</form:select>
```

See: [Spring MVC sample](https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv-spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/attacks/parameterTampering/SelectFieldTampering.jsp)

Regards,

Roberto Velasco (HDIV team)

Comment: Yes, Problem is how ll i can get access of real value in my code if it is showing values as :0,1,2..) once confidentiality activated

Comment: Once you activated confidentiality is not possible to access to real values at client side, they are not available within the HTML. If you need real values, I think you may deactivate confidentiality. In that case HDIV protects you from tampering but values are real values and the end user could see this values but not tamper them.

Comment: Thanks, ll deactivate same :)